# How to add a section after a specific section in a XML file ,c#

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have this XML file:

```
<a>
   <b>
   <name>Ion</name>
   </b>
   <c>
     <article>A10</article>
     <price>100</price>
   </c>
   //here I want to add a new section
   <f>....</f>
   </b>
</a>
```

I want to add section :

```
 <d>
     <info1>test</info1>
     <info2>test 2</info2>
 </d>
```

after section `<c>` ,between ''.

I wrote this code in c# to add define and add section d:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file.Directory + "//" + file.Name);
XElement newElement = new XElement("d",
                                       new XElement("info1", txtInfo1.Text),
                                       new XElement("info2", txtInfo2.Text)
                    );
doc.Element("a").Add(newElement);
```

But with this code I add `<d>` section in `<a>` tag and I want to add after `<c>` section (`<a><b><c>...</c><d>...<d/><f>...</f></b></a>`)

Comment: You have closing `</b>` tag but there is no opening tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 string path = file.Directory + "//" + file.Name;
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
 doc.Root.Element("b").Add(newElement); 
 doc.Save(path); // save document
```

UPDATE (adding between `c` and `f`):

```
 doc.Root.Element("b").Element("c").AddAfterSelf(newElement);
```

Comment: Thanks.
It works fine ,but I forgot something .
After <c> section  I have also a <f> section.And my new section i want to add between <c> and <f>.

Comment: @user1577242 I've updated answer - use `AddAfterSelf` method (which adds a sibling to current element) instead of `Add` (which adds child to current element)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're adding it to the wrong tag. Based on your question you want it added to `b`:

```
doc.Root.Element("b").Add(newElement);
```

Comment: I added `Root` - looks like you missed that in a rush :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky, ah yes. Thanks a lot! The `Element` method is hierarchically constrained. I guess the other way you'd have to use `Descendants`, but almost certainly not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `doc.Element("a").Add(newElement);`

try this:

```
doc.Root.Element("b").Add(newElement);
```